# Producer-Consumer With a Twist

Tags: multithreading, producer-consumer, lockless

So, I'm trying to solve what essentially is a producer-consumer problem, but slightly different.

- "Producer" thread creates tokens and adds them to a list
- "Consumer" thread scans the list of tokens and processes them.
- As a result of the processing some tokens may be removed, and others may stay a bit longer.

So the main difference is that producer's outputs can be removed from the list in an arbitrary order, not necessarily FIFO.

Now, I am thinking about the synchronization for the structure shared between two threads. I want to have a lockless structure. I know about lockless queues, however a queue doesn't fit the use case very well because of reasons described above. One can still use a queue for this as follows:

- Dequeue a token and process it
- If it should not be removed yet, enqueue it back

However, I'd like to avoid it if possible. Ideally what I want is a lockless singly linked list that one thread can append to, while another thread can remove arbitrary elements from. Can you point me to some implementations or papers on that?

Comment: A lock-free priority queue?

Comment: Patents for these data structures are filed in the cabinet labeled "perpetuum mobile".